# Device is in safe mode. Cannot start any stream!

Tags: ros, asus-xtion-pro-live, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use my Asus Xtion Pro Live on Ubuntu 12.04, running ROS Groovy. When I try to use the command `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`, I'm faced with this error:

```
Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1401772289.477038700]: 1. device on bus 001:02 is a Xtion Pro (600) from ASUS (1d27) with serial id ''
[ INFO] [1401772289.480929348]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1401772289.535944795]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @ /home/andrew/catkin_ws/src/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 99 : creating depth generator failed. Reason: Device is in safe mode. Cannot start any stream!
```

I'm very puzzled because it was working perfectly fine just yesterday and I did not change anything at all. Running `rosrun openni_camera openni_node` produces the same error. I have OpenNI v1.5.7.10 installed, and Sensor-Bin v5.1.6.6 installed. I'm using the rollback_usb branch for openni_camera. Would anyone know what happened? Did my Asus Xtion Pro Live hardware itself malfunction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172643/device-is-in-safe-mode.-cannot-start-any-stream!/) by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 324 on 2014-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-06-05**:
I replaced my device with a brand new one and it works, and when I replug the first one, I get the same error message again. What happened to my old Asus Xtion Pro Live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like the hardware failed. I sent it back to my vendor for a 1-to-1 exchange and got a new set. As to what caused it, I'm not sure.

---

Originally posted by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) with karma: 324 on 2014-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1